# How to set ListView At the end of page

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism, stacklayout

I already use  VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" then also left space at the end anyone has an idea about this.
I already try collection view in that also same issue I faced

[image: This is my page]

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
         <ffimageloading:CachedImage Margin="10" x:Name="ImageData"
                         IsVisible="{Binding IsImageURL}"
                         IsEnabled="{Binding IsImageURL}"
                         Source="{Binding ImageURL}"
                         HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="200"
                         HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                         VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                         BackgroundColor="Transparent" Aspect="Fill" >
         </ffimageloading:CachedImage>

         <ListView x:Name="QuizzesAnsList" BackgroundColor="Blue"
                      ios:ListView.RowAnimationsEnabled="false"
                      VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      SelectionMode="None"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                      HasUnevenRows="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding QuizzesQuestionAnswersList}"
                      SeparatorVisibility="None" >
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0" Margin="0,5,0,0">

                                    <Frame  VerticalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}" BorderColor="{Binding BorderColor}" HasShadow="False"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  CornerRadius="2"  Padding="5" >
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                                            <material:MaterialLabel Margin="5" Text="{Binding AnswerText}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="17" Style="{Binding FontType,Mode=TwoWay}"                                                                  VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </Frame>

                                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                                                            Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.SelectedQuizeAnswer, Source={x:Reference QuizzesAnsList}}"
                                                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
         </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: please provide us with some code samples of the important parts of your problem, we can't debug code we can't see

Comment: Yeh sure@RicardoDiasMorais

Comment: Hi I found the problem in your code. you list items static or dynamic

Comment: I'm guessing that if your StackLayout wraps the whole page content, you should add another stack containing the image and the listview, and then that StackLayout should have End on the VerticalOptions, so do the list and image

Comment: and also remember, if you don't have enough items on your listview, of course you will have that space, the list view doesn't "expand" the more items you have, it's an scrollable layout

Comment: What is the behaviour if instead of 4 items, you have like 8?

Comment: Items are dynamic@DelpinSusaiRaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem in your code. Actually, The `ListView` has taken the entire page. If your List items static you set the `HeightRequest="100"` in your `ListView` Or your List Items is Dynamic Use `BindableLayout`

```
<StackLayout x:Name="QuizzesAnsList" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding QuizzesQuestionAnswersList}"  VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                                    <Frame  VerticalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}" BorderColor="{Binding BorderColor}" HasShadow="False"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  CornerRadius="2"  Padding="5" >
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >

                                            <material:MaterialLabel Margin="5" Text="{Binding AnswerText}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="17" Style="{Binding FontType,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                        </StackLayout>

                                    </Frame>

                                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                                                            Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.SelectedQuizeAnswer, Source={x:Reference QuizzesAnsList}}"
                                                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                </StackLayout>

                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: I need one more help in this if I am bound only two answers at that time how to increase the height of Box.      
https://prnt.sc/r02uns

Comment: Set `HeightRequest` the StackLayout inside ViewCell